# reliable way to determine whether LineString is inner circle of polygon

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written this basic code, which firstly extracts polygons from a multipolygon and then the particular LineStrings corresponding to inner and outer circles:

```
DECLARE @SomeMultiPolygon GEOGRAPHY = 'MULTIPOLYGON (
((-2 -2, 2 -2, 2 2, -2 2, -2 -2), (-1 -0.5, 0 -0.5, 0 -1.5, -1 -1.5, -1 -0.5), (0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0, 0 1))
, ((-4 -3, -4 -5, 0 -5, 0 -3, -4 -3)))';
SET @SomeMultiPolygon.STSrid = 4326;

DECLARE @i int = 1  
DECLARE @Results TABLE ( Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), PolygonData GEOGRAPHY )  
WHILE @i <= @SomeMultiPolygon.STNumGeometries()  
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (@SomeMultiPolygon.STGeometryN(@i))
        SET @i = @i + 1  
    END 

SELECT 
    Id,
    PolygonData.STGeometryType(), 
    PolygonData, 
    PolygonData.STAsText() AS PolygonWkt,
    PolygonData.NumRings() AS NumberOfRings
FROM @Results

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ParentId INT,
    SubPolygon GEOGRAPHY
)

DECLARE @Id INT, @InnerLoop INT, @SubPolygon GEOGRAPHY;  
SELECT @Id = MAX(Id) FROM @Results    
WHILE @Id >= 1
    BEGIN   
        SELECT @InnerLoop = PolygonData.NumRings() FROM @Results WHERE Id = @Id
        WHILE @InnerLoop > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SubPolygon = PolygonData.RingN(@InnerLoop) FROM @Results WHERE Id = @Id

                INSERT INTO #Temp
                        ( ParentId, SubPolygon )
                VALUES  ( @Id, 
                          @SubPolygon
                          )

                SET @InnerLoop = @InnerLoop - 1;
            END

        SET @Id = @Id - 1                              
    END

SELECT 
    *, 
    SubPolygon.STAsText() AS SubPolygonText,
    SubPolygon.EnvelopeAngle() AS EnvelopeAngle
FROM #Temp
```

Am I right to assume that, if the EnvelopeAngle is less, than 1 degree the LineString corresponds to an inner circle?

Btw, is there a set based approach to achieve the above - I am not really a fan of loops in TSql.

PS:

This is a visualization of the above example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions in order:

> Am I right to assume that, if the EnvelopeAngle is less than 1 degree the LineString corresponds to an inner circle?

No. That is an artifact of your test data, but you cannot make that assertion in general. Your question comes at a good time though as I just learned about EnvelopeAngle the other day. I like to think of it as "how wide (in degrees) is this object?". If you re-scaled all of your objects either up or down, your EnvelopeAngle heuristic no longer works.

But, a heuristic that I might try is for a given ID in your results table, the largest (by area) is the one that contains the others. You could play around with STDifference as well, but area seems the most straightforward.

> [I]s there a set based approach to achieve the above? - I am not really a fan of loops in TSql.

Yes! Here it is:

```
DECLARE @SomeMultiPolygon GEOGRAPHY = 'MULTIPOLYGON (
    (
        (-2 -2, 2 -2, 2 2, -2 2, -2 -2), 
        (-1 -0.5, 0 -0.5, 0 -1.5, -1 -1.5, -1 -0.5), 
        (0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0, 0 1)
    )
    , (
        (-4 -3, -4 -5, 0 -5, 0 -3, -4 -3)
    )
)';
SET @SomeMultiPolygon.STSrid = 4326;

DECLARE @Results TABLE ( 
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    PolygonData GEOGRAPHY 
);

INSERT INTO @Results
        ( [PolygonData] )
SELECT @SomeMultiPolygon.STGeometryN([n].[n])
FROM Util.dbo.[Numbers] AS [n]
WHERE n <= @SomeMultiPolygon.STNumGeometries();

SELECT 
    Id,
    PolygonData.STGeometryType(), 
    PolygonData, 
    PolygonData.STAsText() AS PolygonWkt,
    PolygonData.NumRings() AS NumberOfRings
FROM @Results;

CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    ParentId INT,
    SubPolygon GEOGRAPHY
);

INSERT INTO [#Temp]
        ( [ParentId], [SubPolygon] )
SELECT r.ID, rings.[ring]
FROM @Results AS [r]
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT r.[PolygonData].RingN(n) AS ring
   FROM [Util].[dbo].[Numbers] AS [n]
   WHERE n <= r.[PolygonData].NumRings() 
) AS rings;

SELECT 
    *, 
    SubPolygon.STAsText() AS SubPolygonText,
    SubPolygon.EnvelopeAngle() AS EnvelopeAngle
FROM #Temp
```

Comment: Thanks.  Great, will check tomorrow.